# Assigning the value of a worksheet cell to a constant

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign the value of a worksheet cell to a constant variable in a VBA macro. The logic behind that action is that the end user is supposed to enter the current week in a specified cell before running the Macro. Since this value is going to be reused throughout the macro and I wanted to play it safe, I tried to declare it as a public constant:

```
private const thisWeek as Integer = Range("B1")
```

However I get an error message about a constant value being needed. So, is it even possible to declare a constant like this in VBA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible. As the word suggest it should be *Constant*.

**Workaround:**

```
Public Const weekRange As String = "$B$1"
```

**Then in your code:**

```
Sub Something()
    Dim thisWeek As Integer: thisWeek = Range(weekRange).Value
'~~> some codes here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

From help: You can't use variables, user-defined functions, or intrinsic Visual Basic functions (such as Chr) in expressions assigned to constants.

In your case you have to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was looking to do this myself and came up with this. I use a function:

```
Function insertPNA(strSource As Long) As String

Dim strResult As String

strResult = Replace(strSource, strSource, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits & Actuals").Range("pnacode").Value)

insertPNA = strResult

End Function
```

Whenever I want the pna code I just type insertpna(1). Hope someone finds this useful. (It doesn't have to be "1" obvs, I just used it to minimize typing.)

Comment: I'm getting the "Circular reference between modules" error.