# Constant in VBA referencing a label

Tags: vba, constants

New to VBA.  Was trying to create a constant that references a named column in my worksheet and am getting an error.  Is this something you can do in VBA or is my syntax just wrong?

**Example**:

```
Public Const ColNum As Integer = [SomeColumn].Column
```

Comment: A constant can only be a literal value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning the value of a worksheet cell to a constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951214/assigning-the-value-of-a-worksheet-cell-to-a-constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant must be able to be evaluated at the time the code is *compiled* (ie. before it runs)

This is OK:

```
Const A as Long = 10 'constant value
```

and this:

```
Const B As Long = A 'from another constant
```

or even

```
Const B As Long = A * 10 'constant expression
```

but not this:

```
Const B As Long = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count 'errors
```

because `ActiveSheet.Columns.Count` can only be determined at *runtime*

Comment: OK, that's what I was thinking.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

The compile error tells you what's wrong: *Constant expression required*

In other words, as @roryap mentions, you can only use a literal value for a Constant expression, you can't assign it anything that must be evaluated at runtime.  A possible workaround is to use constant strings (i.e., your range's *Name*) and assign elsewhere as needed

From your parent/main procedure, call on another procedure which will assign to the module-level or public variables

```
Option Explicit
Const MyColumnName as String = "Dave_Column"
Dim ColNum as Integer

Sub main()

    Call InitializeVariables

    'The rest of your code ...
    MsgBox ColNum

End Sub

Sub InitializeVariables()
    'Use this procedure to assign public/module scope variables if needed
    ColNum = Range(MyColumnName).Column

End Sub
```

Alternatively, `ColNum` can be a function with optional parameters, which when left blank would return the range based on the Constant string, or you could specify a different range name/address to return another column number:

```
Option Explicit
Const MyColumnName as String = "Dave_Column"
Sub main()

    MsgBox ColNum

    MsgBox ColNum("H1")

End Sub
Function ColNum(Optional name$) As Integer

    If name = vbNullString Then 
        name = MyColumnName
    End If

    ColNum = Range(name).Column


End Function
```

Note: this will fail if the named range doesn't exist :)